An error occurred during concurrent access within the same transaction in MySQL
When I create a connection using sqlx and attempt to start a transaction with the BeginTxx method, and then concurrently access MySQL through multiple goroutines initiated by the errgroup.Group method within the transaction, I encountered an error with the connection being dropped.
ctx := context.Background()
    txx, err := common.GetDBApp().BeginTxx(ctx, nil)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    group, _ := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)
    f := func() error {
        var id uint64
        err = txx.Get(&id, `select id from t_id where id = 1`)
        require.NoError(t, err)

        return nil
    }
    
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        group.Go(f)
    }
    group.Wait()

I hope to understand the causes of this error.
```go


Transactions are NOT safe for concurrent use.
